# GKTank example is not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth, p2p, gksession

I'm trying to get the GKTank example working with 2 iPhones. Both have bluetooth enabled. I start the app on both devices and tap the screen. The Peer Picker comes up and the devices find each other. If I select one device in the list it says "Waiting for {other iPhone}..." forever. On the {other iPhone} the waiting phone gets grayed out. If I select the device to connect to from both devices at the same time both go into waiting state forever...

The debug log says this if I select the other iPhone on the debugged device:

> 2010-05-30 23:20:24.331 GKTank[2433:4e03] handleEvents started (2)
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:25.269 GKTank[2433:4e03] ~ DNSServiceRegister callback: Ref=135f70, Flags=2, ErrorType=0 name=00oRWv-0A..David‚Äôs iPhone regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:25.375 GKTank[2433:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=2, IFIndex=8 (name=[en2]), ErrorType=0 name=00oRWv-0A..David‚Äôs iPhone regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:30.691 GKTank[2433:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=00K83eS0A..iPhone von Tamara regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:30.855 GKTank[2433:4e03] ~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=13a320, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 fullname=00k83es0a..iphone\032von\032tamara._gktank._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=7200
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:30.872 GKTank[2433:4e03] ** peer 480260628: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:35.215 GKTank[2433:207] ** Stop resolving? potentially previous resolves
>
> 2010-05-30 23:20:35.226 GKTank[2433:207] ********** BEGIN RESOLVE: 480260628

and it stays that way. On the second iPhone the device is listed as not available and grayed out.

If I select each other at the same time it says this:

> 2010-05-30 23:24:31.416 GKTank[2442:4e03] handleEvents started (2)
>
> 2010-05-30 23:24:32.321 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceRegister callback: Ref=135120, Flags=2, ErrorType=0 name=006JiAZ0A..David‚Äôs iPhone regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:24:32.419 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=2, IFIndex=8 (name=[en2]), ErrorType=0 name=006JiAZ0A..David‚Äôs iPhone regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:24:57.156 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=004_n6C0A..iPhone von Tamara regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:24:57.308 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=13a320, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 fullname=004_n6c0a..iphone\032von\032tamara._gktank._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=7200
>
> 2010-05-30 23:24:57.314 GKTank[2442:4e03] ** peer 203104196: oldbusy=0, newbusy=0
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:02.383 GKTank[2442:207] ** Stop resolving? potentially previous resolves
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:02.425 GKTank[2442:207] ********** BEGIN RESOLVE: 203104196
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:13.562 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceQueryRecord callback: Ref=13a320, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 fullname=004_n6c0a..iphone\032von\032tamara._gktank._udp.local. rrtype=16 rrclass=1 rdlen=18 ttl=7200
> 2010-05-30 23:25:13.569 GKTank[2442:4e03] ** peer 203104196: oldbusy=0, newbusy=1
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:33.660 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=0, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=004_n6C0A..iPhone von Tamara regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
> 2010-05-30 23:25:33.671 GKTank[2442:4e03] Peer [203104196] removed? (0).
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:33.683 GKTank[2442:4e03] GKPeer[139f10] 203104196 service count old=1 new=0
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:37.786 GKTank[2442:4e03] ~ DNSServiceBrowse callback: Ref=134f30, Flags=2, IFIndex=-3 (name=[]), ErrorType=0 name=004_n6C0A..iPhone von Tamara regtype=_gktank._udp. domain=local.
>
> 2010-05-30 23:25:37.816 GKTank[2442:4e03] GKPeer[139f10] 203104196 service count old=0 new=1

... and waits forever.
Does anybody know whats wrong with this sample??

Comment: What are the models of iPhones you are using?  Bluetooth networking is only supported on iPhone 3G and later.  First-generation iPhones and first-generation iPod touches do not support Game Kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, turning bluetooth off and on again fixed the issiue :P I love to be dependant on that kind of reliability...